# GoJS Custom node saves default values

Tags: javascript, json, gojs

Based on example http://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html I've created custom node templates that look like the one bellow.

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Action-node",
    $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
                { minSize: new go.Size(40, 40), fill: "#FF9191", stroke: null }),
            $(go.Panel, "Vertical",
                $(go.TextBlock, "Start",
                {
                    font: "8pt Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                    margin: 8,
                    stroke: lightText,
                    editable: true
                },
                new go.Binding("text")),
                $(go.TextBlock, "...",
                {
                    font: "8pt Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                    margin: 8,
                    stroke: lightText,
                    editable: true
                },
                new go.Binding("text", "subtitle"))
            )
        ),
        // three named ports, one on each side except the top, all output only:
        makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
        makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, false),
        makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, false),
        makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
    ));
```

Problem is that save button (save() function) that calls

```
myDiagram.model.toJson();
```

saves only default values to json string. Other things like location and and link are saved correctly. Is there a problem with my custom template or how can I save changes on node values in graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is that if some code (perhaps because of user action) changes some **GraphObject** property (such as **Node.location** or **TextBlock.text**) and you want the changed value to be reflected in the node data object, you use a TwoWay **Binding** on that property.

Read more about data binding at http://gojs.net/latest/intro/dataBinding.html, especially the last section.

As that last section suggests, when you have a **TextBlock** that is **editable** it is normally the case that you want to make the **Binding** TwoWay.  Are those the property values that you were hoping to be saved automatically in the **Model**?